# Why will a pipe hold water pressure, but not air pressure?

Tags: plumbing

I have a long underground galvanized pipe for my water system.

I was testing the network by compressing it with air at the pressure of 6 bar,and monitored it for 2 hours and the pressure was stable, but in the second day I found it zero.

After that I tested it using water and the pressure remained stable for 3 days.

What is the explanation for this?

Comment: More crucially, does it matter if it holds air pressure for only 24 hours since it holds water pressure and you're using it for water?

Comment: A fault in your testing equipment explains this.

Comment: Could be a fiber seal that is only tight when wet.

Comment: I use the same equipment

Comment: And if you pressure it with helium or hydrogen , it will leak even more.  I would check the connections for leaks ; pressure with air and use soap water to look for bubbles ( standard leak detection).

Comment: I can't check the connection becaus the pipe underground

Comment: Maybe somebody opened a faucet or valve during your first test.

Comment: No iam sour no body opened the valve

Answer (score 5):

Water is approximately 200 times denser than air so the very tiny leaks that can allow air to escape are too small for water.

In industry we do similar testing with less dense gasses like helium to see if it will leak as air is denser so if the helium is leaking below a specific rate we know it won’t leak air.  Check out helium leak testing if interested.

Comment: Or , no mater how inconvenient it is you have a leak.

Comment: Not with water apparently as I suggested because of a difference in density air may be able to escape but water is not able, go to oil even denser yet. He may now find with all the threads and seals wetted there is no longer a leak.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, presuming you mean the connections and not the solid pipe. As a professor of leaks said ( Texas A & M , mech. E.) , "all connections leak , it is a matter of how much". Possibly a small exaggeration but high pressure helium will go through a lot of connections. NASA aims for very, very, very, small leaks. Refinerys and chem plants aim for  very small leaks . But when holding 700 psi hydrogen ,there will be leaks. Without considering that above 400 F ,hydrogen goes through solid steel. For a domestic water system , let your conscience be your guide as to if you have an acceptable leak.